# How to write a pandas DataFrame that contain UUID to excel using xlsxwriter?

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to write a DataFrame to excel using xlsxwriter. 
I get the following error:

```
"TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'uuid.UUID'> in write()"
```

I can work around the issue by converting the UUID into string myself but I feel it could be done better that that. 
The code that generates the error:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [UUID('00792bdd42ab487daaef62a57e72e226'), UUID('002ff29fbfaf42239aeabc8ddd4e375b')]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

I only have to convert it to string to have it working:

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

To make it worse I'm actually using the UUIDs as index, so it's a lot of extra steps to simply to save the DataFrame to excel.

I'm happy to explore other library than xlsxwriter, but xlwt gave me a similar issue.

Thanks

Comment: lot of extra steps to simply to save the DataFrame to excel,,,,,Well,then stop using excel.

Comment: I don't want to use it :) but to allow users to see the result in an excel file.
I can use a CSV file, but formatting would be nice.

Comment: Neither pandas nor Excel know anything special about UUIDs, so I think converting it to a string is as good as you'll be able to do.

Comment: I'm fine getting a string, I'm just surprised xlsxwriter don't do that for me, especially as in the Traceback I can see:
     # Finally try string.